# PayPal Checkout API - Defining payments as a donation

Tags: paypal

I have set up the option to pay payments from my site with the PayPal system API. Everything has been fine for several months.

In a conversation with PayPal customer service I was told that I am sending the payments in a state of payment (for the purchase of a product) and not a donation

And that makes for mistakes

The problem is that because these are non-profit organizations it should be defined as a donation and not a payment

In this guide I have not found how to set it up: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Checkout flow, probably with a Smart Button.

If you want to use the Donation flow instead, you can create a Donate button via https://www.paypal.com/buttons

If you want the button to be editable so as to change the email of the receiving 'business' account, in step 2 uncheck the option to save the button at PayPal, and when viewing the code click the option above to remove code protection.